# animation is not working with css3 (code is probably right)

Tags: css

i'm trying to animate a button to reverse the gradient in one second 
i wrote this css code :

```
button
{
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#7a7a7a, #5c5c5c);
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom right,#7a7a7a, #5c5c5c);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom right,#7a7a7a, #5c5c5c);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#d8d8d8 5%, #909090 95%);
width:500px;
height:30px;
-webkit-animation: backchange 1s;
animation: backchange 1s;/*this comes last*/
}

@keyframes backchange{
from {background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#8d8d8d, #909090);
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom right,#8d8d8d, #909090);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom right,#8d8d8d, #909090);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#d8d8d8 5%, #909090 95%);}
to {background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#909090, #8d8d8d);
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom right,#909090, #8d8d8d);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom right,#909090, #8d8d8d);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#909090 5%, #d8d8d8 95%);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes backchange{
from {background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#8d8d8d, #909090);
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom right,#8d8d8d, #909090);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom right,#8d8d8d, #909090);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#d8d8d8 5%, #909090 95%);}
to {background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#909090, #8d8d8d);
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom right,#909090, #8d8d8d);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom right,#909090, #8d8d8d);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#909090 5%, #d8d8d8 95%);}
}
```

the from parts are not colored in blue like the to part and the animation is not taking one second its done immediatley
this is the html :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<button>this is a button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me, i want to know what's wrong with the code
 
i'm using Google chrome

Comment: jsFiddle / codepen please!

Answer (score 0):

Animating bckgrounds has still limited support. Specially when you want to change the image (the gradient in your case)

One usual trick to solve that is animating the background position instead of the image.

This, applied to your case. could be something like that:

CSS

```
button
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #7d7d7d 0%, #c0c0c0 40%, #c0c0c0 60%, #7d7d7d 100%);
    background-size: 100% 300%;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backchange{
    from {background-position: 0% 0%;}
    to {background-position: 0% 100%;}
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2wA9/)